# cannot run ADB: the operation requires elevation

Tags: android, react-native, adb

I recently started learning React-Native and was trying to run a project on Android emulator.However, this was succeeded at the first attempt, but now It doesn't, throwing the following error.

> Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
>
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Pavindu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe":
> CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation

Since this is a well known error message,I could find lot of answers regarding this error.The following were the actions I took according to those answers.But none of those helped me.

1. Running both android studio and cmd as administrator
2. Running `cmd /c react-native run-android`
3. Deleting `node_modules` and `npm install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a lot, here is what I did to overcome the problem.

- Copied `/Sdk` folder and pasted it in a different location while keeping the old SDK folder there.
- Deleted `platform-tools` folder in copied SDK folder
- downloaded `platform-tools` from [android site](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) and added it to new SDK folder.
- set new SDK location to `ANDROID_HOME` (I use windows)

and `android/build.properties` file in my react-native project.

`sdk.dir="C:\\path\\to\\new\\sdk"`

When I run `react-native run-android` after these steps,all started working fine.

Note: I know that this seems hacky, but as a help for someone, I decided to write this .

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an Android emulator problem.

Change the AVD setting to use "Use Host GPU."

That'll solve the problem.

[image: gpu image]

Select 'Hardware GLES 2.0' to enable host GPU